# Using an external SSD without TRIM, mainly for read operations

Tags: audio, ssd, libraries, trim

For audio production involving DAWs and orchestral sample libraries, it is recommended that one use a dedicated SSD to store the sample libraries (I don't understand all the details of why this is optimal, but it is supposed to make access to those sampled sounds faster than if they were stored on the same drive as the DAW/Operating System; any insight into the technicalities of this would be welcome as well!).

I have purchased a 1TB Samsung 860 EVO, and a third-party SATA-to-USB 3.0 UASP enclosure. I will be using this to store ~900GB of sample library sounds. Apparently, TRIM is not supported when connecting an SSD via USB 3.0. Will I run into problems because of this fact?

The 900GB of samples will be written to the drive once, and then I will not be writing more information to the drive, only reading. However, in the future, I may want to reformat the entire drive and put different sample libraries on it. Thus, this drive is going to be rarely written to, but when it is written to, it will be following a reformat of the drive.

Can you please let me know of any issues I may have due to the unavailability of TRIM? Will my read speed suffer? After a reformat of the drive, will it be as good as new, and the previous lack of TRIM have no lingering effect?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way NAND flash works - you have 3 operations: read, write, and erase.  There is no "overwrite" - if something in flash has to be overwritten, then an erase-then-write is needed.  Writes are fast, erases are slow.  (Leaving out some details, such as write amplification, for simplicity.)

TRIM tells the SSD firmware that it's OK to erase flash (because the OS won't need the data there anymore) - which can be done in the background - so portions of it can be "ready" for a future write.

If TRIMs are never issued, at some point the drive will have to erase flash every time a write is needed, and it will slow down.  TRIM is the only way for an OS to tell a drive it doesn't need data on a specific place on the storage device.

Reading will not be affected unless writes are happening at the same time.

> The 900GB of samples will be written to the drive once, and then I will not be writing more information to the drive, only reading.

Reading will be absolutely fine

Writing almost a terabyte of data to an SSD may be slower the second or third time you write to the drive.  It's probably still going to be faster than an equivalent mechanical HDD, and if it's only rarely, I agree with your line of thinking.

> Thus, this drive is going to be rarely written to, but when it is written to, it will be following a reformat of the drive.

An OS, when formatting an SSD, can tell it to TRIM almost all the blocks, but this won't actually happen if your USB bridge doesn't support it, so formatting won't improve the situation if it's issued with that USB bridge in place.

- If you have a free SATA port in your PC or laptop, you can connect it there and format there, then use the enclosure for production use.
- You might just consider [buying an adapter that passes through TRIM commands](http://salutepc.altervista.org/ssd-on-usb-3-0-3-1-with-trim-support-windows-linux.html).

Comment: Thanks LawrenceC! If the lack of TRIM has no effect on read speeds, that is great, since I need the SSD's speed for reading, not writing. Question 1) Will standard Read/Write speedtests (e.g. Blackmagic) accurately identify the SSD's read speed, so I could confirm in the future that its read speed is good but write speed has suffered? Question 2) Why would one need to TRIM an SSD when formatting it and erasing all data? I would expect a full erase formatting to return write speeds to original value, since all portions are "newly ready" for writing.

Comment: 1) Blackmagic tests should reflect any slowness - seems it tests by writing data to a folder in the same way as you or any app would.  2) Modern OS's will issue TRIMs when formatting but if your enclosure doesn't forward them, then the OS is stuck.  So you will get the same result as you would with a mechanical HDD - a blank file table is overwritten in the specific areas on the device where the OS looks for that info, and the previous data formerly referenced remains and is eventually clobbered.